# How to get classes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing eclipse plugin. User can either select project or particular package, and i want to find all the classes along with their package information within that project or package. 
So, if user select project, i want to produce file which contain below information,

*com.db.util = com.db.util.QueryService.java, com.db.util.DBParsingService.java
com.xx.dao  = com.xx.dao.DBDao.java, com.xx.dao.EnterpriseDao.java*
.
.
so on.....

I have searched alot but could not find any good way to achieve this.
So far I did following,

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject fProject = root.getProject(projectName);
```

there are methods available in IProject but I am not sure whether i can get any help from this class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JDT to accomplish this. Your entry point will be [IJavaModel](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIJavaModel.html) (retrieved through [JavaCore#create(org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html#create%28org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot%29).